# active_admin form and displaying images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have active_admin form for my Gallery model:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Gallery" do
    f.input :title
    f.input :description
    f.input :file
  end
  f.has_many :images do |ff|
    ff.input :file
  end
  f.actions
end
```

If I edit gallery, it shows me inputs for image file uploading, but I'd also like to show image thumbnail if possible, something like:

```
f.has_many :images do |ff|
  image_to ...
  ff.input :file
end
```

Any idea how can I do this? Models are:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gallery_id, :file
  belongs_to :gallery

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :description, :title, :file, :images_attributes
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need Javascript to do that